# Unir etiquetas yaml y yml

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

La etiqueta [yml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yml) tiene más preguntas que [yaml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml), aparte de tener una descripción.  Supongo que no hay problema para definir como sinónimo una de la otra.
Personalmente creo que [yaml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml) es la indicada a ser la etiqueta principal, ya que es el nombre del formato, sin embargo se entiende que [yml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yml) sea más popular, ya que es la extensión del archivo que comúnmente ven los programadores.

Comment: En [so] está como sinónimo también. Si [tag:yaml] no tiene una descripción, se le puede agregar, no?